# Convergence in Probability of a Double Sequence of Random Variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}}$ denote convergence in probability. Suppose that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have a sequence of random variables {$Y_n^k$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $Y_n^k \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}} X$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, suppose that $Y_n^k \xrightarrow[k \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}}Y_n$. Does it follow that $Y_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}} X$?

The original context in which this came up was trying to prove that if $Y_n^k \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}} 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Y_n^k \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\mathbb{P}} 0$, but I tried to see if I could generalize the result to an arbitrary family of random variable sequences.

Comment: Just take constant random variables: $Y_n^k = \frac{k}{n+k}$ for all $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$. In other words this is just a basic question about limits in general, there is no need to bring probability into the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion does not hold in general. Here is an example. Let $\Omega := (0,1)$ and let $Y^k_n (\omega) := {\bf 1}_{(0, \min\{1,2^{k-n}\})}(\omega), \ \omega \in \Omega$.
Then, $Y^k_n \to 0, n \to \infty$ in probability but $Y^k_n \to {\bf 1}_{(0,1)}, k \to \infty$ in probability. These mean that $X = 0$ and  $Y_n = {\bf 1}_{(0,1)}$ for every $n$. Furthermore, $\sum_{k \ge 1} Y^k_n = +\infty$ for every $n$.